# initializing an object with strings to null

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have an object model somewhat like this:

```
public class MyObject

    {
      public string String1 { get; set; }
      public string String2 { get; set; }
      ...
    }
```

When the object initializes, all the string values are set to null.

Later on, I'm writing a method that evaluates the value of these strings to prepare an update in the DB. Something like this:

```
if (TheObject.String1 != null) { TheObjectInDB.String1 = TheObject.String1; }
if (TheObject.String2 != null) { TheObjectInDB.String2 = TheObject.String1; }
```

TheObject is an instance of MyObject and TheObjectInDB is an instance of the linq-to-sql map for the table I'm updating.

My question is this: is using the null a safe way to do it or could it cause problems later? Should I create a constructor that initializes these strings to "" and in the update check if the strings are = "" instead of = null?

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Yes it is safe. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645756(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Do you mean to set TheObjectInDB.String2 to TheObject.String1 in your sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing more, or less safe about null or an empty string. It is entirely your choice. Because both are often used to indicate the abscence of data or information, there is a convenience method [string.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) that allows you to accept either value.

In your case, I would stick with the easiest option, null.

Answer (score 1):

You could initialize both properties to string.Empty (preferred to "") and then check for string.Empty when setting the properties, however only if you can guarantee that either:-

a) the value being set is never string.Empty

or

b) the value being set is string.Empty but the values are only set once

I'd stick with checking for null to avoid either of the above causing potential issues in the future.

Comment: ok, looks like I'll stick with what I have. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem here, the code you are using should work without any problems. 
I can't even think of 'problems that this can cause 'later''.